# Cannot understand plotting of decision boundary in SVM and LR

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm, svc

For example we have f(x) = x. How to plot it? We take some x then calculate y and doing this operation again, then plot chart by dots. Simple and clear.

But I cannot understand so clearly plotting decision boundary - when we haven't y to plot, only x.

Python code for SVM:

```
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
Y = y
# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data. We do not scale our
# data since we want to plot the support vectors
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(X, Y)
rbf_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C).fit(X, Y)
poly_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C).fit(X, Y)
lin_svc = svm.LinearSVC(C=C).fit(X, Y)

# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))


for i, clf in enumerate((svc, rbf_svc, poly_svc, lin_svc)):
    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will asign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
```

Everything to plot chart goes here, how I understood:

```
    pl.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    pl.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)
    pl.axis('off')

    # Plot also the training points
    pl.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)

pl.show()
```

Can someone explain in words how this plotting works?

Comment: Is `pl.scatter` plotting the line you are asking about? It looks to me like a lot of important code is missing that we'd need to understand the problem.  Maybe it's because I don't know anything about SVM. I think probably the line you are asking about is just contained in X[:,1], but we can't really know unless you say how you initialized X.

Comment: matty T pain, pl.scatter(...) plotting examples of data but not decision boundary. It is library function from pylab.

Comment: have you figured it out yet?  It would help if you posted an image of the figure and tell us which parts you understand and which parts you don't.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you are plotting the function `f : R^2 -> {0,1}` so it is a function from the 2 dimensional space into the degenerated space of only two values - `0` and `1`.

First, you generate the mesh you want to visualize your function on. In case of your example with `f(x)=y` you would select some interval `[x_min,x_max]` on which you would take points with some distance `eps` and plot the corresponding values of `f`

```
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
```

Next, we calculate the function values, in our case it is a `SVM.predict` function, which results in either `0` or `1`

```
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

It is the same as in your example of calculating `f(x)` for all the analyzed `x`

Now, the "tricky" part which may lead to missunderstanding is

```
pl.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)
```

This function plots the contours of your `f` function. To visualize 3 dimensional function on the plane one often creates contour plots, it is like a map of height of your function. You draw a line between points if the large change in the value of `f` is detected around them.

Nice example from the [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContourPlot.html) [image: sample contour plot]

Shows an example of such plot.

In the case of SVM we have **only two possible values** - `0` and `1`, so as the result, the contour lines are located exactly in these parts of your 2d space, where on one side we have `f(x)=0` and on the other `f(x)=1`. So even though it seems like a "2d plot" it is not - this shape, that you can observe (the decision boundary) is a visualization of the biggest differences in the 3d function.

In `sklearn` documentation that visualize it for the multi-classification example, when we have `f : R^2 -> {0,1,2}`, so the idea is exactly the same, but contour is plotted between such adjacent x1 and x2 that `f(x1)!=f(x2)`.

[image: SVM multiclass]